# Matlab face alignment code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I am attempting to do some face recognition and hallucination experiments and in order to get the best results, I first need to ensure all the facial images are aligned. I am using several thousand images for experimenting.

I have been scouring the Internet for past few days and have found many different programs which claim to do so, however due to Matlabs poor backwards compatibility, many of the programs no longer work. I have tried several different programs which don't run as they are calling onto Matlab functions which have since been removed.

The closest I found was using the SIFT algorithm, code found here

http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/ECCV2008/

Which does help align the images, but unfortunately it also downsamples the image, so the result ends up quite blurry looking which would have a negative effect on any experiments  I ran.

Does anyone have any Matlab code samples or be able to point me in the right direction to code that actually aligns faces in a database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can find this recent work on [Face Detection, Pose Estimation and Landmark Localization in the Wild](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/). It has a working Matlab implementation and it is quite a good method.
Once you identify keypoints on all your faces you can morph them into a single reference and work from there.

Comment: I downloaded this code before, but I could not seem to get it working. Under the compile.m, this line "mex -O fconvblas.cc -lmwblas -o fconv" causes an error saying  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -o.

Comment: I did manage to get method 3 running "mex -O fconv.cc" however when I went back to try out on the "multipie_main.m" it says "Error using diary cache/multipie.log: File not found."

Comment: Hey, @AdamM, I'm curious what functions are causing you backward compatibility problems. Feel free to e-mail directly: jeff.mather-at-mathworks.com.

Comment: @AdamM I faced same problem but I had figured out what is going wrong .. open compile.m comment this line mex -O fconvMT.cc -o fconv   then uncomment this line  mex -O fconv.cc   save and run compile again

Comment: change -o with -output

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way it with PCA and the eigen vector. To found X and Y most representative data. So you'll get the direction of the face.

You can found explication in this document : [PCA Aligment](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~taoju/cse554/lectures/lect07_Alignment.pdf)

Comment: Cheers, will have a look over the document now and see how effective it is.

Comment: It really efficient. I use that to align brain image for a school project in C++. But with matlab it gonna be easy, PCA and SVD are already implement no need library

Comment: Do you have any code samples for this alignment code. I have a training set, I have code for PCA and PCA using SVD, but the document you linked me is not very clear on how to perform the alignment using these methods. It says I need to centroid for source and target, but does not explain how to calculate these. Are there any source code examples out there?

Comment: Sorry, @AdamM, I don't have access to my code currently. But later on I'll be able to provide more information. But Dogbert point on something that can help you.

Comment: The website, giassa.met has some useful code, but sadly the PCA registration code is not yet available.

Comment: Sorry, I don't found my old project, but I have my note from class, the problem... it in french... If I have time tonight, I'll maybe make a post about it or search for something that can help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to detect the faces first, or are they already cropped?  If you need to detect the faces, you can use `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

To align the faces you can try the `imregister` function in the Image Processing Toolbox.  Alternatively, you can use a feature-based approach.  The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes a number of interest point detectors, feature descriptors, and a `matchFeatures` function to match the descriptors between a pair of images.  You can then use the `estimateGeometricTransform` function to estimate an affine or even a projective transformation between two images. See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the vision.CascadeObjectDetector toolbox. However I did download some code that does an automatic crop, although only works on front facing images. I looked through imregister code, and I found some examples for aligning an two images that were the same, just one was rotated. Are there any examples of imregister being used with different facial images?